# Android Studio 1.4.1 - Impossible to exclude .iml files in Subversion

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, version-control, svnignore

it's frustrating, i uploaded my project to **subversion** and everything is perfect.

but I can not ignore the ***.iml** files and **local.properties**

the folders are ignored correctly, but the files are not ignored.

[image: Here is my ignored files and folders]

Comment: where is located that file ?

Comment: @rekire: there is nothing like a .svnignore file.. svn stores ignored files in a so called "svn property"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an svn client to set the svn-property "svn:ignore" to your wished setting. svn supports wildcards like "*.iml". It is easiest in tortoisesvn but also possible via commandline:

```
svn propedit <Your Directory>
```